# Are the sets $\{(x, y): x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and $\{(x, y): 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Are the sets $A = \{(x, y): x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and $B = \{(x, y): 0 <
>  x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ homeomorphic?

My guess is that they are not, but I do not know how to prove this. I have studied some topology only in the context of metric spaces, and I know that connectedness and compactness are topological properties, but I don't know if that applies here.

Comment: The sets you are describing are a unity disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the unity disk with a hole at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not. The set $A$ has this property: for every compact subset $K$ of $A$, there is a compact subset $K^*$ of $A$ such that $K\subset K^*\subset A$ and that $A\setminus K^*$ is connected. But this doesn't hold for $B$; take$$K=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,x^2+y^2=\frac14\right\}.$$

Comment: How does this property going to help here? 'for every compact subset $K$ of $A$, there is a compact $K^*$ such that $K\subset K^*\subset A$ and that $A\setminus K^*$ is connected.'

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Since $A$ has that property and $B$ hasn't, they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: How to prove this property preserve under homeomorphism?Can you please give some hints?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan All you need is that being compact and being connected are both preserved under homeomorphism.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I was going to write this out anyway in case it helped someone, as it was not obvious to me immediately. 
Suppose $A$ has this property and is homeomorphic to $B$. Then $B$ has this property too. Let $f$ be a homeomorphism from $B$ to $A$. Suppose $K$ is a compact subset of $B$. Then $f(K)$ is compact in $A$. We have some set $K'$ compact in $A$ with $f(K) \subset K' \subset A$ and $A \setminus K'$ is connected. Then $f^{-1}(K')$ is compact in $B$ and contains $K$, and $B \setminus f^{-1}(K') = f^{-1}(A \setminus K') $ is connected.

Comment: Thank you very much sir @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Thank you very much @Anu

Answer (score 5):

$A$ is a simply connected space and $B$ is not...